# google Gae php: Custom Not Found Url

Tags: google-app-engine

I am using google app engine to upload my php files.
For example this is my testing url `http://testing12399234.appspot.com/index.php` , whenever the url is not found i want the page to point to `http://testing12399234.appspot.com/index.php` , for example visiting `http://testing12399234.appspot.com/randomblabla12312` must show contents of `http://testing12399234.appspot.com/index.php` . I know its possible via  .htaccess .But how to use .htaaccess in google GAE

Answer (score 0):

The app.yaml file holds the handlers for your application.  The first handler that matches the requested URL is used to serve the request.  In the linked documentation the last handler is:

```
- url: /.*
  script: not_found.php
```

So this will match any URL that hasn't already been matched, and send it to your custom not found page.  Just make sure it is the last handler in your configuration file, or it will take precedence over other handlers.

[Google AppEngine PHP AppConfig documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appconfig)